# python sk-video reading mp4 with variable frame rate - missing frames

Tags: python, video-processing, frame-rate, scikits

I have some video files captured via Windows Camera app. The files are saved in mp4 format with variable frame rate.

When I read a video file using

```
vrf_video = skvideo.io.vread(video_path)
frame_sk = vrf_video[index]
```

I see that the last frames of the video are missing when compared to reading the video using

```
vrf_vid_cv2 = cv2.VideoCapture(in_path)
ret, frame_cv2 = vrf_vid_cv2.read()
```

So I wonder why, where did the last frames go when reading them in the sk-video package?

Reproducible code:

```
import cv2
import skvideo
skvideo.setFFmpegPath(ffmpeg_path)
import skvideo.io
vrf_vid = skvideo.io.vread(video_path)
idx = 0
while True:
    vrf_vid_frame = vrf_vid[idx]
    cv2.imshow('vrf frame', vrf_vid_frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
    if key == 27: # esc key
        break
    elif key == 46:  # ">"
        idx = idx + 1
    elif key == 44:  # "<"
        idx = max(0, idx-1)
```

The last frame of the video is not the last frame in the list.
Works with every video shot with Windows Camera app.

Comment: please provide sample data and a reasonably complete [mre]. if this is reproducible with constant frame rate, you can generate test video with ffmpeg and `testsrc` source -- does `vread()` give you the entire video as a numpy array, or is `vrf_video` some object that overloads `__getitem__`? -- I've removed the OpenCV tag. this should be checkable with any suitable method of reading the video, e.g. unpacking to frames with ffmpeg, or opening in a video player and frame-stepping near the end.

Comment: consider browsing that library's issues https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video/issues and perhaps filing this as an issue

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I edited the question with reproducible script.
vread() gives an entire video as an numpy array.
I unpacked the frames using ffmpeg, the last parsed frame is not the last frame in the numpy array.

When loading a constant frame rate video, there is no issue.

Comment: yeah sounds like you could submit that as an issue to `scikit-video`. make sure to attach a test video to the issue so there's no doubt about how to reproduce the issue.